# Varying number of Decimals per column

Tags: tables, formatting

I have a table

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
A      & B      & C      \\
1.00   & 1.10   & 1.11   \\
10.00  & 10.10  & 10.11  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and I would like to format it such that column A shows 0 decimals, column B shows one, and column C shows two decimals. Is it possible to specify the number of decimals shown by column?

In my real task, numbers are pulled from knitr, but I would think I can handle this in LaTeX rather than R.

Comment: I changed the code in the sample table to use `tabular` rather than `tabularx`, since none of the columns employ the `X` column type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of `siunitx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{S[round-mode=places, round-precision=0, table-format=2]
                S[round-mode=places, round-precision=1, table-format=2.1]
                S[round-mode=places, round-precision=2, table-format=2.2]}
{A}    & {B}    & {C}    \\
1.00   & 1.10   & 1.11   \\
10.00  & 10.10  & 10.11  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

To right alin non-numerical inputs, you can use the following new `\mc` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{r}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{S[round-mode=places, round-precision=0, table-format=2]
                S[round-mode=places, round-precision=1, table-format=2.1]
                S[round-mode=places, round-precision=2, table-format=2.2]}
\mc{A}    & \mc{B}    & \mc{C}    \\
1.00   & 1.10   & 1.11   \\
10.00  & 10.10  & 10.11  \\
\mc{---}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In principle, exactly what solves the problem!The column type appears to expect only numerical input. Input such as `---` for missing values or longer word words in the column heading produce errors. Is there a workaround for these cases?

Comment: Place non-numerical entries in a set of `{}` as I did with the column headers in the example document.

Comment: overlooked, thanks! I noticed that they are not right-aligned within the column, even when using `table-alignment = right` as another option. Can this be adjusted, as well?

Comment: @bumblebee: Non-numerical inputs are horizontally centered by default. I have edited my answer to include an example on how to right align them instead.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I have posted this as a separate question now. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532482/no-right-alignment-in-siunitx-with-long-titles

Answer (score 1):

> In my real task, numbers are pulled from knitr, but I would think I can handle this in LaTeX rather than R.

Why? There is no reason to do things the hard way `:)`

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl,xcolor}
\begin{document}
R raw data with whatever decimals places: 
<<thedata,echo=F>>=
df <- data.frame(
  A=c(1.00,10.00),
  B=c(1.10,10.10),
  C=c(1.11,10.11))
df
@

The same data with 0, 1 and 2  decimals in a nice \LaTeX\ format:
<<after,results='asis', echo=F>>=
library(xtable)
print(xtable(df, digits=c(0,0,1,2)),booktabs=T, include.rownames = F) 
# note that length of digits vector is 1+n  columns
@
\end{document}
```