# no right alignment in siunitx with long titles

Tags: tables, siunitx, alignment

I have a table with two columns, the only difference is the length of the title. I use `siunitx` to format numeric output and its `table-alignment=right` to have things right-aligned. This works well with the short title but not with the long one. Am I misunderstanding something here?

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-alignment = right, round-mode=off, round-precision=0, table-format=5]
                S[table-alignment = right, round-mode=off, round-precision=0, table-format=5]}
{title}   & {superlongtitle}    \\
11111     & 11111               \\
22222     & 22222               \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output with problem]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why it works, but setting the specifications with `\sisetup` before the `tabular` environment, and repeating `table-alignment=right` for columns with a long title, works:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}

     \begin{table}
     \sisetup{table-alignment=right, round-mode=off, round-precision=0, table-format=5}
    \begin{tabular}{SS[table-alignment=right]S}
    {title} & {superlongtitle} &{title} \\
    11111 & 11111 & 11111 \\
    22222 & 22222 & 22222 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: @Mico's comment on the options order leads to the following, more compact, code (thanks,@Mico!):

```
   \begin{table}
     \sisetup{table-format=5, table-alignment=right, round-mode=off, round-precision=0}
    \begin{tabular}{SSS}
    {title} & {superlongtitle} &{title} \\
    11111 & 11111 & 11111 \\
    22222 & 22222 & 22222 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: +1. One also gets the desired result if one places the `table-format` option *before* the `table-alignment` option. No idea why this workd either.

Comment: That's quite  weird…

Comment: Mico, this really did the trick beyond the MWE above. Technically, this is also the order silently showed in the vignette. However, this really could be more explicit.